# Give an example of a finite ring $R$ and polynomials $f, g\in R[X]$ such that the polynomial division of $f$ by $g$ is not unique

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

> Give an example of a finite ring $R$ and polynomials $f, g\in R[X]$ such that the polynomial division of $f$ by $g$ is not unique.

I know that $f$ can be written as $\sum_na_nX^n$ and $g$ can be written as $\sum_mb_mX^m$, and I know that $\deg(f+g)\leq\max(m,n)$, and $\deg(f\cdot g)\leq \deg(f)+\deg(g)$.

But I don't know how to work on this problem. Please any help.

Comment: $2xx = 2x(x+2)$ in $\,\Bbb Z_4[x].\ $ That should give you an idea of how to generale many more exmples.

Comment: @BillDubuque Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur So the OP can learn and give an answer and receive feedback on it.

Comment: @BillDubuque Sure. But you can do that just as well, or even better, in an answer post.

Comment: @BillDubuque I didnt understand your example

Comment: @JOJO  in my example $\,f = (2x) x = (2x)(x+2)\ $ so we can choose $\,g = 2x\ \ $

Comment: How is $f$ = $(2x)x=(2x)(x+2)$? and How is their division not UNIQUE?

Comment: It's $\mathrm{deg} (fg) \leq\mathrm {deg} (f) +\mathrm {deg} (g) $.

Comment: Because  $2(2) = 0$ in $\Bbb Z_4.\ $  Both $x$ and $x+2$ are valid quotients for $\,2x^2 \div 2x\,$ so the quotient is not unique.

Comment: @BillDubuque so here, you divided $f = 2x^2$ by $g = 2x$? But how is "$x+2$" a quotient?

Comment: Both values works as quotients $q$ for  division, i.e. $\,f  = q\,g + r\,$ with $\deg r < \deg g\ $ (here $\,r = 0\,$ in both cases).

Comment: okay thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

To get this off the unanswered queue,

> $2x^2=2(x^2+2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$.

*Answer by Bill Dubuque*

To add on to this, ring with zero divisors provide many examples. For instance, when working with $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$, there are always such polynomials when $n$ is not a prime.